# PHP if-statement failure on Register Form

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have this bit of code:

```
if(isset($_POST['register_form'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) &&
       isset($_POST['password']) &&
       isset($_POST['lastname']) &&
       isset($_POST['email'])) {
         Register();
       }
    else {
      echo 'It seems like some information is missing. Please fill in the whole form.';
    }
  }
```

That applies to the following form:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Register Form</legend>
      <input type="text" name="username" maxlenght="32" placeholder="Username"/> <br />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> <br />
      <input type="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" /> <br />
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" maxlenght="1024" /> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register_form" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

I know that this is wrong. Since the if-statement only checks if there is actually a "Username", "Password", etc. form, but it doesn't check if it empty or not.
But I don't know how to check if it is not filled in properly. If someone could help me, that'd be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well first you have to determine what is valid before you can check it. If you just want to check for empty values look at something like [strlen](http://us3.php.net/strlen) or possibly [empty](http://us3.php.net/empty).

Comment: `empty()` `strlen()==0` `==''` any of those work.  `trim()` the inputs as well to ensure they just didn't put in a space or two.

Comment: Everyday we see this kind of questions, and everytime there are billion of answers with practices that I would never accept ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset()` will always return true in this case. If you want to check if these form values are empty, use `empty()` instead.

Comment: No, `isset` will only return `true` if those variables are set (e.g., using the form in the example); if the file is called by other means not *all* variables might be set.

Comment: That's why I wrote that `isset()` will always return true _in this case_. Of couse I'm assuming he is using the code in his question.

Comment: But a malicious attacker might not use all those variables and things might go horribly wrong. *Never* trust user content!

Comment: Of course he can double check `if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))` :)

Comment: I just read this on php.net: _No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false._ So it should be enough to check for `empty()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine. Of course I also use htmlspecialchars($_POST['x']) to prevent cross script writing. (It's enought to just use htmlspecialchars()?)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$error = 0;    
(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != "") ? $username = $_POST['username'] : $error++;

if($error > 0) echo "error";
```

This checks that its set and that it does not == "". Else it will return an error flag which you can check later.

This will obviously need editing to fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for validation. For server side validation, you can write something like this:

```
function validate($value){
     if(isset($value) && !empty($value)){
        return true;
     }else{
        return false;
     }
}


if(validate($_POST['username']) &&
       validate($_POST['password']) &&
       validate($_POST['lastname']) &&
       validate($_POST['email'])) {
         Register();
    }
    else {
      echo 'It seems like some information is missing. Please fill in the whole form.';
  }
```

Comment: [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) also checks for availability of a variable, so no need to check if it `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a hassle, but it's better practice to not only check if it's set, but ensure a null isn't being passed through. You should create a list of errors depending on what the problem is, so the user better understands what is wrong as well.

```
$errors = array( 'error' => true,
                 'username' => false,
                 'password' => false,
                 'lastname' => false,
                 'email' => false);

if(isset($_POST['register_form'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != ''){
        $errors['username'] = true;
    }else{
        $errors['username'] = 'Please set a username';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] != ''){
        $errors['password'] = true;
    }else{
        $errors['password'] = 'Please set a password';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['lastname']) && $_POST['lastname'] != ''){
        $errors['lastname'] = true;
    }else{
        $errors['lastname'] = 'Please set a lastname';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''){
        $errors['email'] = true;
    }else{
        $errors['email'] = 'Please set an email';
    }
}

if($errors === true){
    return $errors;
}else{
    $errors['error'] = false;
    return $errors;
}

return false;
```

This way, upon returning, you can use JS to print errors accoring to the php response, and use the $errors['error'] spot as the JS test to see if it even has to print any, if it's false, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have functions for such a checking. For this particular case I'd use my function for array key checking:

```
function check_key($key, $array) {
    if (isset($array[$key]) && (! empty($array[$key])))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You could use it like that:

```
if(check_key('register_form', $_POST)
    if(check_key('username', $_POST) && check_key('password', $_POST) 
    && check_key('lastname', $_POST) && check_key('email', $_POST) )
        Register();
else
  echo 'It seems like some information is missing. Please fill in the whole form.';
```

Comment: Here we have a function to perform both checking on isset and being not empty. I used this function instead of just isset checking. As for code changes, I removed curve brackets where they are not needed.